# NSImage initWithData not found?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, class, nsimage

In [NSImage class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsimage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/initWithData%3a) it is said that there exist method `initWithData`, but why xCode says it doesn't exist?

I use it like this:

```
    NSData *imgData = [[imageView image] TIFFRepresentation];
fotoImg = [NSImage initWithData:imgData];
```

And i get warning:

```
Class method '+initWithData:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `[[NSImage alloc] initWithData..`

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `initWithData` on the class when you should call it on an instance of that class. Do this: `[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];`

It is very important to learn the difference between member functions and class functions (or in Obj C terms "messages"). I recommend http://www.amazon.de/Programming-Objective-C-Automatic-Reference-Developers/dp/0321811909/ref=pd_sim_sbs_eb_1/276-1733140-9413556.

Comment: there is no "static way" in Objective-C. They are class methods and instance methods. The call is always dynamic.

Comment: Alright I corrected it. I didn't mean static as opposed to dynamic but you're right, it's not the correct term here.

Comment: God, I was having this problem but with NSImage initWIthContentsOfFile and you really saved me a lot of time.  I was converting code from iOS's [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile] and just changed the class and method name assuming it would work.  Brain fart moment, for sure.  Hopefully if anyone has the same issue they wind up seeing this comment.